# Any Way to Auto Guarded Timestamps?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

```php
$fillable = ['*']

Model::create($request->all()); // frontend can inject 'created_at'
```

---

```php
$guarded = ['created_at', 'updated_at', 'deleted_at']
```

Can we auto guard timestamp?

---

I don't want to do this:

```php
$fillable = ['field_1........field_20']
```

Comment: This is such a bad practice that I don't even know where to begin. So in essence 1. you should have "whitelisted" key-value pairs that are allowed in the request 2. you should validate those values and 3. if there is a key-value in the request that is not whitelisted you should consider it a wrong request and respond with some 4xx response

Answer (score 1):

You can use except() method of Illuminate\Http\Request that will return all request fields but will exclude of the list the specified keys.

```
// try this...
Model::create($request->except('created_at', 'updated_at', 'deleted_at'));
```

You can create a BaseRequest class that override the Illuminate\Http\Request, same as:

```
<?php

namespace YourClass\Name\Space;

class BaseRequest extends Illuminate\Http\Request
{
    const EXCEPT_FIELDS = ['created_at', 'updated_at', 'deleted_at'];

    public function all()
    {
        return $this->except(self::EXCEPT_FIELDS);
    }
}
```

and inject the new BaseRequest class into your controller instead of the Illuminate\Http\Request class.